# How can I use array to schedule post by php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$task = array(
                "t2"    => array("10:11","12:00","23:18"),
                "t3"    => array("08:00","11:30"),
    );
$post = array("post 1","post 2","post 3","post 4","post 5","post 6","post 7");
```

Hi everybody,
How can I use array to schedule post by php? I have tried use foreach but it's not working for me :(

I want to get schedule such as:

```
Post 1: T2 at 10:11
Post 2: T2 at 12:00
Post 3: T2 at 23:18
Post 4: T3 at 08:00
Post 5: T3 at 11:30
Post 6: T2 at 10:11
Post 7: T2 at 12:00
```

.......

Please help me about this :)

Comment: Looks like you are serialize the array as the `$post` array.

Comment: But you need to link the task with the post?, how you set the post1 takes t2 or t3?

Comment: Are you trying to fire a task at a particular time?  What do you mean by 'schedule post'?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$tasks = array(
    "t2"    => array("10:11","12:00","23:18"),
    "t3"    => array("08:00","11:30"),
);
$posts = array("post 1","post 2","post 3","post 4","post 5","post 6","post 7");


$i = 0; $output = '';
$t = count($posts);
while (true) {
    foreach ($tasks as $key => $times) {
        foreach($times as $time) {
            if($i == $t) break(3);
            $output .= sprintf("%s: %s at %s\n", ucfirst($posts[$i]), ucfirst($key), $time);
            $i++;
        }
    }
};
print $output;

/* Outputs:

Post 1: T2 at 10:11
Post 2: T2 at 12:00
Post 3: T2 at 23:18
Post 4: T3 at 08:00
Post 5: T3 at 11:30
Post 6: T2 at 10:11
Post 7: T2 at 12:00

*/
```

Comment: Re-reading the original question, I think the OP is really asking about scheduling a job queue.

Answer (score 0):

You need this one. First of all you need to make an array like that is easy to access and flexible, While creating the array you need to store the total amount of data, cause your post use the same data recursively. Here i create a `$total` variable to store the total value and check in the second foreach loop for greater than or not if it is then just set the current looping variable `$i` to 0 again for access the array from the first index.

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/BrnHK)

```
$task = array(
            "t2"    => array("10:11","12:00","23:18"),
            "t3"    => array("08:00","11:30"),
        );
$post = array("post 1","post 2","post 3","post 4","post 5","post 6","post 7");

$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($task as $k => $t){
    foreach($t as $tas){
        $arr[$i++] = array($k, $tas);
    }
}
$total = $i - 1;
$i = 0;
foreach($post as $val){
    if($i > $total)
        $i = 0;
    echo ucfirst($val).": ".ucfirst($arr[$i][0])." at ".$arr[$i][1]."\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$task =  array(
    array("t2", "10:11"),
    array("t2", "12:00"),
    array("t2", "23:18"),
    array("t3", "08:00"),
    array("t3", "11:30")
);

$post = array("post 1","post 2","post 3","post 4","post 5","post 6","post 7");

$taskIndex = 0;

foreach($post as $p)
{
    $idx = $taskIndex % sizeof($task);
    echo($p.': '.$task[$idx][0].' at '.$task[$idx][1].'<br>');
    $taskIndex++;
}
```